# CSS Top / Left properties and Jquery animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

On a page i have two divs lets say Left_Div and Right_Div. On right div i have multiple images positioned using Top and Left properties of CSS. Left_Div is used as a left panel and On a button click I animate Left_Div and Right_Div to slide right and Left_Div becomes visible. Just like left menu on facebook iphone app.

```
 $("#Right_Div").animate({ marginLeft: "600px" }, 500);    
 $("#LeftDiv").animate({ width: "600px", opacity: 1 }, 500);
```

The problem is that when Left_Div and Right_Div slide then images that are positioned by using Left and Right attributes do not move and as a result they overlap Left_Div. Anyone please help me how i can move images with DIVs.

I don't want to rest top/left properties again because there are so many images and they are loaded dynamically.

I hope that i have explained my question :)

Comment: Did you tried floating images?

Comment: Means `float:left;` for the images of left division and `float:right;` for the images of right division.

Comment: I added small fiddle to my answer, demonstrating the effect floating has when other elements are moved or re-sized. Add your specific HTML and CSS to it and start applying the floating logic you want, if you get stuck getting it to work, post your fiddle and/or code you are using and I'm sure we can get it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want dynamic movements you cannot give exact positions.

By saying an image is a set amount of pixels from the left the image will always be exactly there, no matter what.

You would have to use a floating logic whereby you assign for example `float: left` or `float: right` to all your components you want to line up beside each other on the left or right.

Then when you are moving an element all other elements which are set to float beside it will move along with it.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YMAyw/) - floating example using your animation logic

In the DEMO you can now see how elements move with each other when when floating is applied.

The DEMO above has the following HTML:

```
<div id="Left_Div">My left div</div>
<div id="anotherLeftdiv">My other left div</div>
<div id="anotherRightdiv">My other right div</div>
<div id="Right_Div">my right div</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#Left_Div, #anotherLeftdiv{
    float: left;
}

#Right_Div, #anotherRightdiv{
 float: right;   
}
```

Script:

```
$("#Left_Div").animate({ width: "150px", opacity: 1 }, 500);
$("#anotherRightdiv").animate({ marginRight: "100px" }, 500);
```

I hope this makes sense. Without your exact current CSS and HTML it is hard to tell you exactly what it is you have to change.

**Edit**
I added 4 images to the right div and placed them into the 4 corners using `float` and `clear` instead of fixed positioning.

They will simply move along with the animation of the div, as long a they do **not** get any fixed positions.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QUzg2/) - Animation with floating images

The images are in a div container, by using `float: left` and `clear: right`for example you are telling the image to go all the way to the left and force a break to the right of it. Thus any other image using float: left will be forced to go in the row below.

The same applies to the `float:right` and `clear: right`, those settings force the image to stay right and force a break to the right of it, forcing any other `float: right` to go into the line below.

See the images in the HTML:

```
<div id="Right_Div">
    <img class="left" src="http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/19/3318010/Eraser.png"/>
    <img class="right" src="http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/19/3318010/Script.png"/>
    <img class="left" src="http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/19/3318010/Ok.png"/>
    <img class="right" src="http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/19/3318010/Decrease%20time.png"/>
</div>​
```

The styles to force images into their corners:

```
img.left{
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}

img.right{
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

I hope this helps. You should have plenty to play around with now.

If you come across any issue now with your specific implementation or any CSS you can't work out, it would be easier to complete this question and ask a new one posting the specific code you are having issues with.

Comment: @Tanveer: Has this worked out for you or do you need any more information?

Comment: thanks @ François , You have understood my issue. Just think that in ur example, in right div we display multiple images on different positions with top left positions and when this div animates , images donot move with div they maintain their positions. Do i need to animate those images as well or there is any other way? I hope that i have explained the issue

Comment: @Tanveer: I added an example using floating images. Just keep clicking the `Run` button at the top-left to re-run the animation. Fiddle around with the code and hopefully you can start applying this to your code now :)

Comment: Thanks @ François i worked on ur idea and find out the solution. Thanks for support

Comment: You are more than welcome. Glad to hear you got it sorted out.